# Grouping_ID output not matching with theoretical output

Tags: sql, binary, grouping

I have a question based on the above explanation, I have the following problem regarding the grouping_ID

I will illustrate my code (the important bits) in order to better show my problem

```
SELECT GROUPING_ID( [Description], AccountNumber, Scheme) AS 'GroupingID'
```

.
.
.
.

```
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((Scheme, AccountNumber)
       , (Scheme, AccountNumber, [Description])
       , (Scheme)    
       , ([Description])
```

I understood the Grouping_ID function using the following link:http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510624.aspx

The way I understand grouping_ID is that the grouping_ID function assigns a binary value to each grouping set. This is then converted to a base10 number and assigned as the grouping_ID output. based on the above, my grouping_ID (my mental calculation). Can anyone tell me what the expected grouping_IDs should be? I calculate the following:

```
(Scheme, AccountNumber) =3
(Scheme, AccountNumber, [Description]) = 7
(Scheme) = 1
([Description]) = 4
```

I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

With `GROUPING_ID([Description], AccountNumber, Scheme)` the numers are assigned like this:

```
Description = 1 << 1 = 1
AccountNumber = 1 << 2 = 2
Scheme = 1 << 3 = 4
```

So:

```
(Scheme, AccountNumber) = 6
(Scheme, AccountNumber, [Description]) = 7
(Scheme) = 4
([Description]) = 1
```

Where did you get the wrong base numbers from? The order of the numbers is exactly like specified in the arguments to the `GROUPING_ID` function.

Comment: Thanks. I calculated the base10 numbers by converting the binary based on the example in the link I attached in the original question. So using the GROUPING_ID([Description], AccountNumber, Scheme), the binary for (Scheme, AccountNumber) = 011. Converting this to base10, I get 3. Is this not correct?